# Running Total with negate field

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to make a running total like this in crystal report, what should I do?

```
type         unit  running total
subcription   100            100
subcription    50            150
redemption     25            125
subcription    30            155
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula, which returns either positive or negative value, depend on type. Create running total on said formula.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable for your running total, lets call it run_tot.  On each detail line have a formula like:

```
Shared NumberVar run_tot;

if {table.type}="subscription" then
   run_tot=run_tot+unit;   // subscription - add quantity.
else
   run_tot=run_tot-unit;   // Anything but subscriptions, minus quantity.
```

You can add multiple conditions to handle each "type"